# How to dynamically call dbt macros using jinja?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I have a use case where I would like to define the name of a macro and then apply it to one column.

A simplified example could be as follows. I have two macros defined that I want to call dynamically in my model (both take one column as an input):

- cast_to_string
- convert_empty_string_to_null_value

Now, I want to call them dynamically. See the example below

```
{%- set macro_names = ["cast_to_string", "convert_empty_string_to_null_value"] -%}

select
    {% for macro_name in macro_names %} 
        -- this should dynamically be evaluated to `{{ cast_to_string(my_column) }}`
        -- and `{{ convert_empty_string_to_null_value(my_column) }}`
        {{ macro_name(my_column) }} 
    {% endfor %}
from my_model
```

However, this will throw an error saying that a string is not callable.
I also tried using `{% raw %} {{ {% endraw %}` to escape brackets, but that didn’t work either.

So, my question is, if there is a way to dynamically call macros in jinja/dbt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work if you remove the quotes :
`{%- set macro_names = [cast_to_string, convert_empty_string_to_null_value] -%}`

So that jinja doesn't interpret it as string and you can use it as a Callable

I achieve it using this example :

```
{%- set macro_names = [print_lower, print_upper] -%}

{% for macro_name in macro_names %} 
    {{ macro_name("test") }} 
{% endfor %}
```

and

```
{% macro print_lower(string) %}
    {{ print(string|lower) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

```
{% macro print_upper(string) %}
    {{ print(string|upper) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

[image]

Comment: That makes sense! With the quotes - you wrote "brackets," but I understood what you meant - the variable is a string and is interpreted as a string in the SQL code. Without the quotes, the variable name is a callable function. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, i updated my response to make it clearer!

Answer (score 1):

Use context to get

```
{%- macro run_dinamic_macro(macro_name, params) -%}
    {{ context[macro_name](params) }}
{%- endmacro -%}
```